# snooker ball collision detection

Tags: opencv, collision-detection

i trying to detect the initial colour a white ball hits on a snooker table. I will be using a camera looking down on table so balls move in x and y direction. I have the snooker balls detected and their colours using opencv. just trying to implement a way of tracking which ball the white touches first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ball collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767205/ball-collision-detection)

Answer (score 1):

Track white ball path - when the direction changes assume that was a hit

At the point the direction changes find the distance from the center of the white ball to center each other ball.

The ball it hit must be the closest distance (and presumably must be 1 ball diameter away!)

Comment: thats a good idea. thanks. how would you go about tracking path of white ball?

Comment: if you can detect the ball, you can detect it's center, if you do this in each frame then the change in x,y of the center is it's path

Comment: I would generalize "direction change" as detecting change in the X and Y velocities, e.g. a perfectly centered collision where the white ball direction does not change but rather slows or stops completely.

Comment: ah yes. cheers. il have to come up with something for the bouncing off cushions but that should work

Comment: @Dave - thanks didn't think of that. That's the problem with not having a mis-spent youth hanging around pool halls :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with the foreground, in which each moving ball will be a blob. First moving blob to appear is the white ball, second one is the first ball hit. Then check the whole image to know the color of that ball.

Comment: that seems easier to implement for what im doing. as i only need to know first 2 moving blobs. how would i go about implementing that?

Comment: I think you still need to check that the ball is close to the white one, if there are two not white balls attached each other, if the white one hit one of them even the second one will move and so you will see 3 blobs by doing background subtraction