# color ball collision

Tags: c, opencv, colors, collision-detection

```
for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
{
     // round the floats to an int
     float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
     cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
     int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
     //uchar* ptr;
     //ptr = cvPtr2D(img, center.y, center.x, NULL);
     //printf("B: %d G: %d R: %d\n", ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2]);
     CvScalar s;

     s = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
    printf("B: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);

     // draw the circle center
     cvCircle(img, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

     // draw the circle outline
     cvCircle(img, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

     //display coordinates
     printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
```

the code above detects 22 colored balls and extracts rgb value of each ball. ican use this rgb value to determine color of each ball. i am trying to implement detection of which color ball the white ball hits first. my idea was to wait for white balls centre to change(i.e. move) and the next color ball whose center changes is the ball it hits. but i am having trouble coding this?

Comment: You've already asked this exact same question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767205/ball-collision-detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the previous x,y in variables, and check them every iteration, to determinate if they had changed.
I recommend you, instead of this, to check the distance between the center of the white ball to the center of the others - a collision is when the distance is the sum of the radiuses.

BTW, It's not C.

Comment: i was going to do this but the circle detection is slightly off so not all balls are detected as same radius so thats why im going with my way. would you be able to help with the saving of the x,y please? thanks

Comment: just declare arrays `int oldx[22],oldy[22]` (and init them to the first coordinates of the circles), and every time you recalculate the circles, compare the new values and the olds, and put the new values in oldx[i],oldy[i].

Comment: how would i initialise them for each circle.     int old[22]= {center.x,center.x, center.x etc} how would i make center.x specific for each circle?

Comment: Use a loop. (probably similar to the one in the question)

Comment: one last question. how would i get the first non white ball that moves instead of recording all the balls?

Comment: its a video of a snooker game. so no code will be moving balls

Comment: well, in the loop, you can check for every ball if it moved. If more than one had (right after that the white moved), your movie has a problem...

Comment: if multiple balls move, i wont know which one moved first so?